# automatically close batch file when done

Tags: batch-file

How would I make this close itself when its done?

```
copy h2.cfg default.cfg /y
c:
cd "c:\program\reba"
"c:\program\reba\reba.exe"
```

i tried adding:

```
cls
@exit
```

in the end but i didnt work

edit: i want the cmd window to close when reba has loaded

Comment: Yeah, this should close itself fine on the end if reba.exe exits correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to run `reba.exe` in the background.

The shell command `START` should do the trick for you. Here is some documentation on it:

http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

I think you can say something like

```
START "" "c:\program\reba\reba.exe"
```

in your batch file (i.e. just add the `START`).

Comment: Note that you should never blindly use spaces around the first argument when dealing with `start`. This causes the argument to be interpreted as the window title for the new window and then the program to run is missing. Which means it will just spawn a new `cmd` window with the respective window title.

Comment: Ah, very interesting! That's why the doc I quoted makes those mysterious admonitions that you should always include a title, without giving a sensible reason why. This clears things up, thanks!